# LibreOffice Writer: Crear un campo dinámico que tenga la fecha actual + 30 días

Tags: date

Estoy buscando en **LibreOffice Writer** alguna manera de hacer referencia a la fecha y poder hacer cálculos con ella como sumar 30 días o poner una condición si sobrepasa alguna fecha poner esa fecha límite.

He visto las fórmulas pero sólo veo (SUM, Round, Percent,... seno, coseno,etc...) Pero pocas más.

El objetivo final sería hacer un campo que: Si la fecha actual + 30 días sobrepasa una fecha límite, entonces poner la fecha límite y si no, poner la fecha actual + 30 días.

Muchas gracias.

Añado imagen para intentar dejarlo más claro:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si intento poner una función condicional que muestre la fecha no funciona. (He probado con =NOW(), =TODAY(), =AHORA()... con el símbolo de igual, sin el símbolo, con los paréntesis, sin los paréntesis.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final Lo he resuelto creando una Macro al abrir el documento que recorra todos los campos y cuando encuentre el campo de Fecha Fija, entonces que ponga el valor de los minutos de diferencia en el campo Adjust

```
Sub run_at_Open
    'Declaro Variables y les pongo valor
    dim FechaLimite as date
    dim FechaFin as date
    dim MinsAFechaLimite as double
    dim MinsAFechaFin as double
    FechaLimite = "31/05/" & YEAR(NOW()) 'Fecha límite 31 de Mayo del año actual
    FechaFin = Cstr(DateAdd("d", 30, DATE())) 'Días de plazo 30 (Si se cambian los días, comprobar en el campo de fuera también)

    MinsAFechaLimite=DATEDIFF("n", DATE(), FechaLimite)
    MinsAFechaFin=DATEDIFF("n", DATE(), FechaFin)

    'Recorro los campos del documento
    oTextfields = thiscomponent.Textfields
    oTextfieldsEnumeration = oTextfields.createEnumeration
    While oTextfieldsEnumeration.hasmoreelements
       oTextfield = oTextfieldsEnumeration.nextelement
       if (oTextfield.IsFixed) then 'Si es el campo fijo es el que hay que cambiar
           if (MinsAFechaLimite<MinsAFechaFin) then 'Si es mayor de 0 es la fecha que está adelantada y la que hay que poner el límite
                oTextfield.Adjust=MinsAFechaLimite
           else
                oTextfield.Adjust=MinsAFechaFin
           end if
        end if
    wend
End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

No se yo, si habrás buscado mucho, he puesto en google: "fecha actual libreoffice calc" -> Primer link (https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Date_and_Time_Functions/es) donde aparecen unas cuantas funcionas para manipulación de horas. Pero bueno, ya que contesto lo haré bien.

Si solo te interesa la fecha (sin hora) podrías usar

```
=HOY()
```

Si te interesa tener la hora también podrías usar

```
=AHORA()
```

Una vez tengas la fecha, puedes manipularla como prefieras, por seguir un poco la linea de tu duda, si quieres:

> El objetivo final sería hacer un campo que: Si la fecha actual + 30 días sobrepasa una fecha límite, entonces poner la fecha límite y si no, poner la fecha actual + 30 días.

El ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La segunda linea sería el ejemplo, y la tercera linea las funciones que he utilizado, para lo que haría falta ponerles el "=" delante. (ej: =HOY()) Excepto la fecha limite que he metido una fecha cualquiera a mano.

Para información acerca de estas formulas: https://help.libreoffice.org/

Comment: Hola Diego. Gracias por tu respuesta. Pero como puedes ver al inicio de mi pregunta en negrita, quiero usar esas mismas funciones (las de Calc) pero en *** Writer ****, que no están... Las he intentado usar (=HOY(), =TODAY(), =NOW(), =AHORA())  pero no funcionan. El objetivo es que un campo ponga la fecha final de un periodo.

Comment: Entonces me disculpo por lo primero, habré leido mal, en ese caso no se muy bien que es lo que podrías hacer.

Comment: Gracias de todas maneras, Diego.